# How do I check a NSObject item in a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
self.tabBar.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context:tabBarContext)



override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    println(change)
    if context == tabBarContext && keyPath == "hidden"{
        //how to check if change[new] is 1 or 0
    }
}
```

When I print `change` I get:

```
[kind: 1, new: 0]
```

I want to be able to check whether "new" is 0 or 1. How can I typecast it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  constant string provided by KVO **NSKeyValueChangeNewKey**.

```
let newChange = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try unwrap

```
if let dictChange: Dictionary<String, Int>  = change as? Dictionary<String, Int> {
      let isNew = dictChange["new"]
}
```